# Help identifying bonsai tree

Tags: identification, trees, bonsai

My friend gifted me a bonsai tree on my birthday a few days ago (super excited!). Unfortunately it was bought to me without a tag and therefore, as I don't have any experience with bonsai trees yet, I have no idea what tree it is and it could complicate my care for it as well. 
It was left in a cold car (winters are terribly cold out here and it definitely was below zero) for a bit too long (have to point it out - not by me, I already love it too much), therefore it lost quite a bit of its leaves and doesn't look as gorgeous as it could. It stopped loosing them though, so I think it's a good sign.
I would really appreciate if someone helped to identify it, as I really want to be able to take a proper care of it.
Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: An olive bonsai?

Answer (score 1):

Either olive or [podocarpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podocarpus) based on the leaf shape.
Incidentally looks like you have some leaf drop off. In bonsai this is usually from keeping the tree indoors, where microscopic pests feed on the sap and kill leaves. The solution is to actually keep it outside (as long as the species is suitable for your local climate), or if not a green house (don't forget to water well and very regularly in this case!)

Comment: I second *Podocarpus*, the leaves look similar to it. The style however is not usual for this species.